# Find elements that are not in the DOM using Selenium Java

Tags: java, html, selenium, maps, layer

I am trying to find elements in a map, anyway these elements are not in the D.O.M but they are loaded in an image, this image should be a layer.

```
<img decoding="sync" id="id" src="https:x=96&amp;transparent=true&amp;format=png32&amp;layers=show%3A-1%2C-1%2C-1%2C0&amp;bbox=1018794.0340374347%2C5693xxx156&amp;bboxSR=102100&amp;imageSR=102100&amp;size=1600%2C415&amp;f=image" style="position: absolute; width: 1600px; height: 415px; transform: translate(93px, -655px); transition: -webkit-transform 500ms ease 0s;">
```

[image]

The elements i have to find are these coloured dots(red, yellow, etc..)

[image]

I can open tha layer alone in the browser but it's not very helpful
[image]

I tried Sikuli but it's unreliable.

Is there any way to do this?

Thank you.

PS: i had to remove part of the HTML due to privacy.